# How to format output in date and time from Log Files and delete duplicate entry from the output

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, grep

I have got output from several different log file.I am using below command to filter out from log file.I need the output filter out by date and time and all the output should be display in sorting order by date and time.And all the result should be consolidated into one file.I am searching the Profiling User having @ABC and @DEF and also delete the duplicate entries.

```
cat log_file1.log | grep 'Profiling user :' | awk '{print $1,$21}' | cut -c2- | grep '@ABC'
```

Output from log_file1.log

```
    2016-05-16T10:50:09.170+00:00] ABHIJEET.VADGAMA@ABC.com
    2016-05-16T10:50:09.170+00:00] ABHIJEET.VADGAMA@ABC.com
    2016-05-16T10:56:43.944+00:00] AAMIR.SHAIKH@ABC.com
    2016-05-16T10:56:43.944+00:00] AAMIR.SHAIKH@ABC.com
    2016-05-16T11:00:55.961+00:00] SALIL.WAGLE@ABC.com
    2016-05-16T11:00:55.961+00:00] SALIL.WAGLE@ABC.com
    2016-05-16T11:12:23.326+00:00] ABHIJEET.VADGAMA@ABC.com
    2016-05-16T11:12:23.326+00:00] ABHIJEET.VADGAMA@ABC.com
    2016-05-16T11:26:35.311+00:00] VIPIN.SHARMA@ABC.com
    2016-05-16T11:26:35.311+00:00] VIPIN.SHARMA@ABC.com
    2016-05-16T12:08:33.719+00:00] PRITHA.MAZUMDAR@ABC.com
    2016-05-16T12:08:33.719+00:00] PRITHA.MAZUMDAR@ABC.com
    2016-05-16T12:58:40.453+00:00] VIPIN.SHARMA@ABC.com
    2016-05-16T12:58:40.453+00:00] VIPIN.SHARMA@ABC.com
    2016-05-16T13:44:45.657+00:00] PRITHA.MAZUMDAR@ABC.com
    2016-05-16T13:44:45.657+00:00] PRITHA.MAZUMDAR@ABC.com
    2016-05-16T14:42:35.818+00:00] HOLLY.M.JOHNSONSTUHR@ABC.com
    2016-05-16T14:42:35.818+00:00] HOLLY.M.JOHNSONSTUHR@ABC.com
    2016-05-16T14:46:07.353+00:00] CLEAVAN.R.DSOUZA@JPMORGAN.COM
```

Output from log_file2.log

```
2016-05-12T08:16:49.438+00:00] SABEEN.RAZA@ABC.com
2016-05-12T08:16:49.438+00:00] SABEEN.RAZA@ABC.com
2016-05-12T08:32:52.239+00:00] AKPOME.O.OMORHIRHI@ABC.com
2016-05-12T08:32:52.239+00:00] AKPOME.O.OMORHIRHI@ABC.com
2016-05-12T08:52:19.074+00:00] PUNIT.X.KHIRODWALA@JPMORGAN.COM
2016-05-12T08:52:19.074+00:00] PUNIT.X.KHIRODWALA@JPMORGAN.COM
2016-05-12T09:39:48.475+00:00] GRAZYNA.M.JANKOWSKA@JPMORGAN.COM
2016-05-12T09:39:48.475+00:00] GRAZYNA.M.JANKOWSKA@JPMORGAN.COM
2016-05-12T09:58:42.659+00:00] PRIYANKA.V.GAIKWAD@ABC.com
2016-05-12T09:58:42.659+00:00] PRIYANKA.V.GAIKWAD@ABC.com
2016-05-12T11:45:58.756+00:00] ABHIJEET.VADGAMA@ABC.com
2016-05-12T11:45:58.756+00:00] ABHIJEET.VADGAMA@ABC.com
2016-05-12T12:36:02.116+00:00] SHANE.L.BERGENSTEN@ABC.com
2016-05-12T12:36:02.116+00:00] SHANE.L.BERGENSTEN@ABC.com
2016-05-12T13:03:52.589+00:00] VIPIN.SHARMA@ABC.com
2016-05-12T13:03:52.589+00:00] VIPIN.SHARMA@ABC.com
```

cat logfile_3.log | grep 'Profiling user :' | awk '{print $1,$21}' | cut -c2- | grep '@DEF'

```
2016-05-12T13:50:40.132+00:00] PRIYANKA.V.GAIKWAD@DEF.com
2016-05-12T13:50:40.132+00:00] PRIYANKA.V.GAIKWAD@DEF.com
2016-05-12T14:06:32.173+00:00] VIPIN.SHARMA@DEF.com
2016-05-12T14:06:32.173+00:00] VIPIN.SHARMA@DEF.com
```

I need Output as below :-

```
  Date       Time               User 
    2016-05-16  8:16:49     SABEEN.RAZA@ABC.com
    2016-05-16  8:16:49     SABEEN.RAZA@ABC.com
    2016-05-16  8:32:52     AKPOME.O.OMORHIRHI@ABC.com
    2016-05-16  8:32:52     AKPOME.O.OMORHIRHI@ABC.com
    2016-05-16  8:52:19     PUNIT.X.KHIRODWALA@JPMORGAN.COM
    2016-05-16  8:52:19     PUNIT.X.KHIRODWALA@JPMORGAN.COM
    2016-05-16  9:39:48     GRAZYNA.M.JANKOWSKA@JPMORGAN.COM
    2016-05-16  9:39:48     GRAZYNA.M.JANKOWSKA@JPMORGAN.COM
    2016-05-16  9:58:42     PRIYANKA.V.GAIKWAD@ABC.com
    2016-05-16  9:58:42     PRIYANKA.V.GAIKWAD@ABC.com
    2016-05-16  11:45:58    ABHIJEET.VADGAMA@ABC.com
    2016-05-16  11:45:58    ABHIJEET.VADGAMA@ABC.com
    2016-05-16  12:36:02    SHANE.L.BERGENSTEN@ABC.com
    2016-05-16  12:36:02    SHANE.L.BERGENSTEN@ABC.com
    2016-05-16  13:03:52    VIPIN.SHARMA@ABC.com
    2016-05-16  13:03:52    VIPIN.SHARMA@ABC.com
    2016-05-16  13:50:40    PRIYANKA.V.GAIKWAD@DEF.com
    2016-05-16  13:50:40    PRIYANKA.V.GAIKWAD@DEF.com
    2016-05-16  14:06:32    VIPIN.SHARMA@DEF.com
    2016-05-16  14:06:32    VIPIN.SHARMA@DEF.com
    2016-05-16  10:50:09    ABHIJEET.VADGAMA@ABC.com
    2016-05-16  10:56:43    AAMIR.SHAIKH@ABC.com
    2016-05-16  10:56:43    AAMIR.SHAIKH@ABC.com
    2016-05-16  10:50:09    ABHIJEET.VADGAMA@ABC.com
    2016-05-16  11:00:55    SALIL.WAGLE@ABC.com
    2016-05-16  11:00:55    SALIL.WAGLE@ABC.com
    2016-05-16  11:12:23    ABHIJEET.VADGAMA@ABC.com
```

Comment: Don't use `grep` and `cut` in the same pipeline as `awk`. `awk` can do everything `grep` and `cut` can.

Comment: Hint: look up `split` in the `awk` manual.

Comment: @Michael Vehrs ;- how to use awk command to do all stuff.at lleast let know how to filter out in `5/12/2016   8:16:49     SABEEN.RAZA@ABC.com `

Comment: @Ajinkya Well, the basic building block of `awk` programs is `PATTERN { ACTION ... }`. So, instead of using `grep`, you can say `/Profiling user:/ { do whatever }`.

Comment: You are OK with throwing away time-zone information? Is it all in one time-zone?

Comment: I want in `5/12/2016   8:16:49     SABEEN.RAZA@ABC.com` format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial solution, using a **sane date format**:

```
/Profiling user :/ && ($21 ~ "@ABC.com" || $21 ~ "@DEF.com") {
    split($1, time, "[^0-9]");
    print time[4] "/" time[3] "/" time[2] "\t" $21;
}
```

Comment: I used this command got the below result but i could get the time  `cat b.log | awk '/Profiling user :/ && ($21 ~ "@ABC" || $21 ~ "@DEF") {    split($1, time, "[^0-9]");    print time[4] "-" time[3] "-" time[2] "\t"   $21;}'`                       `12-05-2016      AB.RAZA@ABC.COM`
`12-05-2016      BEEN.RAZA@ABC.COM`

Comment: thanks a lot i find the your way .. `cat b.log | awk '/Profiling user :/ && ($21 ~ "@DEF" || $21 ~ "@ABC") {    split($1, time, "[^0-9]");    print time[4] "-" time[3] "-" time[2] "\t" time[5]":"time[6]":" time[7]  "\t"   $21;}'`

Comment: @Ajinkya Don't use `cat` like this. `awk` takes file name arguments.